# How to add prefix to react native text input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, styled-components, textinput

So I have a string of text which I'm trying to add in-front of a TextInput. I made that string of text a non-editable TextInput due to alignment issues.

The problem I'm facing is, I couldn't get the editable TextInput content to wrap. I've tried wrapping it all inside Text but it made the whole content non editable, I've also tried changing TemplateNameContainer to Text but that didn't make any difference other than messing up the alignment. Is there a way to wrap the CustomTextInput value?

Code:

```
<TextInputContainer isFocused={isFocused}>
  {templateName && seqNo ? (
    <TemplateNameContainer onPress={this.focusInput} activeOpacity={1}>
      <TemplateName editable={false} pointerEvents="none" isFocused={isFocused}>
        {`${templateName} #${seqNo}:`}
      </TemplateName>
    </TemplateNameContainer>
  ) : null}
  <CustomTextInput
    ref={this.onRef}
    onFocus={onStartEditing}
    onBlur={onStopEditing}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    onSubmitEditing={saveTitle}
    returnKeyType="done"
    isFocused={isFocused}
    multiline={true}
    blurOnSubmit={true}
  >
    {isFocused ? editedTitle : title}
  </CustomTextInput>
</TextInputContainer>
```

Styles:

```
const TextInputContainer = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: ${colors.brightLight};
  align-self: flex-start;
  border-radius: ${radius.small};
  color: ${colors.primary};
  margin-left: -${spacing.space_s};
  padding-bottom: ${spacing.space_xl};
  ${props =>
    props.isFocused &&
    `
  background-color: ${colors.lightCyan};
  `};
`;

const CustomTextInput = styled.TextInput`
  height: auto;
  background-color: ${colors.brightLight};
  flex: 1;
  padding: ${spacing.space_inset_s};
  color: ${colors.primary};
  font-size: ${fonts.t1};
  line-height: ${scale(20)};
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: ${radius.small};
  ${props =>
    props.isFocused &&
    `
  background-color: ${colors.lightCyan};
  `};
  ${props =>
    props.inObjective &&
    `
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: ${fonts.t2};
  `};
`;

const TemplateNameContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
`;

const TemplateName = styled(CustomTextInput)`
  padding-right: 0;
`;
```

What I am trying to do

[image: What I'm trying to do]

What I ended up with

[image: What I ended up with]

Comment: you able to solve this?